# How to add a field at the run time in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry and is stucked at a place .I have a custom dropdown menu , I want that if I select the second option from menu a field should be added and again if I select the first option from the menu the same field should be deleted.Here is my custom dropdown.

```
       public FWCustomChoiceField(final Object choice[]) {
    edit_field = GlobalUtils.getImage(Display.getWidth() + "x"+ Display.getHeight() + "bb_dropdown1.png");

    this.choice = new Object[choice.length];
    this.choice = choice;
    text = choice[0].toString();
    choiceField = new ListField() {
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            //buttonIndexFunctionality(getSelectedIndex());

            Field focus = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getLeafFieldWithFocus();
            if (focus instanceof ListField) {
                ChoicePopupScreen popup = new ChoicePopupScreen(20, Display.getHeight()/ 2 - (choice.length * 20), choice);
                popup.setChoice(choice);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(popup);
            }
            return super.navigationClick(status, time);
        }
    };



    choiceField.setSize(1);
    choiceField.setCallback(new TestListCallback());
    add(choiceField);
    invalidate();
}
    public int getListFieldIndex()
{

    return choiceField.getSelectedIndex();
}

public void setSelIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
    this.text = choice[index].toString();
    choiceField.invalidate();
}

public String getValue() {
    String value = choice[index1].toString();
    return value;

}

public int getSelectedIndex() {
    return index;
}
```

I searched and found that I need to rebuild the screen at run time but not able to figure it out how to do it.

Comment: add a field manager(hfm / vfm) to the screen. if you click the second menu, add the corresponding field to the field manager and invalidate it. When you click the first option, remove the field from the field manager.

Comment: I am doing the same thing but unable to do it at run time. When i click on submit button than the field is added.

Comment: you want to change the field when you click the drop down na ?. is that on run time ?

Comment: Ya this is what i want to ... as soon as i select the second option a field should be added immediately....

Comment: on the selection event of your drop down, add a field to the screen. on the next selection , remove that field.

Answer (score 0):

First create a Field manager and add it to your screen.

```
 VerticalFieldManager title1;
 title1=new VerticalFieldManager(FIELD_HCENTER)
           {

           };
 title1.add(new NullField());
 add(title1);
```

Now when you select the second item on the drop down, do the following -

```
title1.deleteAll();
title1.add(add your field);//here add your field to title1.
title1.invalidate();
```

When you click the first item on the drop down, -

```
title1.deleteAll();
title1.invalidate();
```